# How to (deep)copy a map from a const object

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, constants, deep-copy

I have another problem I can't seem to solve..., or find on this site...

I have an object (called DataObject) with a map, declared as follows:

```
std::map<size_t, DataElement*> dataElements;
```

Now i have a copy function (used in the copy constructor):

```
void DataObject::copy(DataObject const &other) {

    //here some code to clean up the old data in this object...

    //copy all the elements:
    size = other.getSize();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            DataElement* dat = new DataElement(*other.dataElements[i]);
            dataElements[i] = dat;
    }

}
```

This doesn't compile, since dataElements[i] is not possible on a const object. How do I make a deep copy of all the elements in the map that is owned by a const object?

I know that the find() function is possible on a const map, but then how do I get to the actual object that I want to copy?

Comment: what is the error? What is DataElement? What parameters its constructor takes?

Comment: Your function isn't marked const, so how is dataElements const?

Comment: If your keys run from 0 to N it is almost certain by the way that map is the incorrect collection for what you are trying to do. Why not just use vector or deque?

Comment: Does the map need to contain pointers? Since you are using the copy constructor for the elements you obviously don't have derived types/ So your map could just contain objects and then the copy would happen automatically with the default copy constructor.

Comment: @DeadMG: My function is not marked const, but the copy constructor has to take a const object, and you cannot modify members of a const object.

Comment: @CashCow: you are right, I should probably use a vector, but I ran into this, and was wondering how to solve it..

Comment: @user: So you want to .. copy an object by modifying it? That's flawed.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't understand. I don't _want_ to modify the object, its just that there is no const version of the [] operator of the std map. The compiler thinks that I _could be_ modifying the object (when asking for an index that doesn't exist). See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5B%5D/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::map<size_t, DataElement*>::const_iterator it = other.dataElements.begin();
while(it != other.dataElements.end())
{
    dataElements[it->first] = new DataElement(*(it->second));
    ++it;
}
```

I'm almost positive this should work.

Comment: It will work but if your map has an element already at that location you will overwrite it thus losing the pointer you have to delete (and will get a leak). You should check for this first.

Comment: If "...some code to clean up the old data..." empties this->dataElements, this code is fine.

Comment: It needs to delete dataElements[it->first] if it existed. This would work: void replace(DataElement*& old, DataElement* newv) { delete old; old=newv } then put replace(dataElements[it->first],new DataElement(*(it->second)));

Comment: @CashCow -- As Useless said, according to OP's comment, "//here some code to clean up the old data in this object...
" the old data was already cleaned up.

Comment: @PigBen so we are assuming the map we are writing to is empty, in which case it will work fine.

Comment: I indeed clean the map (and delete the referred objects) first. This works very well!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use std::transform. This does a copy whilst also performing a function on each element. In your case a deep copy of the value.

This will therefore do as a transformer:

```
class DeepCopyMapPointer
{
   typedef std::map<size_t, DataElement*> map_type;
   typedef map_type::value_type value_type;

public:
   value_type operator()( const value_type & other ) const
   {
      return value_type(other.first, new DataElement(*other.second) );
   }
};

void DataObject::copy(DataObject const &other) 
{
   std::transform(other.dataElements.begin(), other.dataElements.end(),
      std::inserter( dataElements, dataElements.end() ), DeepCopyMapPointer() );
}
```

It's not quite that simple because if you do duplicate an element and your insert fails as a result you will get a leak. You could get round that by writing your own inserter instead of std::inserter... a bit tricky but that's your next exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Since your map just has integer keys from `0` to `n - 1`, just change your container type to a vector, and your current code should work nicely (you'll need to resize the destination container to make sure there's enough room available).

If you need to use `map` for some reason (existing API?), as you discovered `operator[]` has only a non-const version.

Instead use a `const_iterator` approach (upvoted and taken from @PigBen's answer):

```
std::map<size_t, DataElement*>::const_iterator it = other.dataElements.begin();
while(it != other.dataElements.end())
{
    dataElements[it->first] = new DataElement(*(it->second));
    ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have much time to answer now so this will be brief.  There is a copy-constructor for map, but it won't do a deep copy.  You want to use iterators (map.begin(), map.end()).  *Iter  will give you a pair object, so you can do  (*iter).first and/or (*iter).second.  (Or something like that... It's been a while...)

Ref: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto& kv : other.dataElements) {
            dataElements[kv.first] = new DataElement(*kv.second);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just one observation :- You are giving direct access to the dataElements. (other.dataElements). Keep dataElements private and then give method like GetDataElement.

Comment: No, it is the same class. It probably is private but another instance of the same class will have access, as private is not a "per object" access specifier.

Comment: Dont do that. Get/Set methods are the antithesis of encapsulation. Also note an class is **always** a friend of itself. So it can easily access the other objects elements. This does **NOT** break encapsulation as the objects are meant to know about each other (as they are the same type how can they not know the implementation details of each other).

Comment: I indeed always learned that it is okay to do that in a copyconstructor (or a function like this, that is used in the copy constructor). The members of DataObject and DataElement are of course private.